# (PHP PDO) What is the difference?

Tags: php, pdo

I don't understand the difference between two following code block. The first block is longer than the second and I have to determine the type of `$id => PDO::PARAM_INT, $name => PDO::PARAM_STR`. The second is concise. Please help me understand the difference between them. Thank you so much.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:id AND name=:name");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:id AND name=:name");
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':id' => $id));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Please let me know what should I use? I know that two above code blocks have the same result. But which way should i use?

Comment: what about reading PDO's documentation?

Comment: What is the difference? Two of them have the same result. The second is easy to code than the first. Or you cannot answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is largely down to preference. Placing the parameters within the `execute()` call is a shorter way of doing the same thing as expressly binding the parameters via `bindValue`. `bindParam` acts slightly differently. Note that all variables submitted via `execute()` are treated as strings, no matter what.

The advantage of the longer method is that you get to force data types - which is considered good practice - and it also allows for easier NULL inserts. You can, with `bindParam` also work with the variable before execution as its value is only submitted at the exact moment of the `execute()` call.